# Let $\mathcal{S}$ be the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing $\left\{(r,s]:r,s\in \mathbb{Q}\right\}$. Is $\mathcal{S}$ the collection of Borel sets?

Tags: measure-theory, proof-explanation, borel-sets

> Let $\mathcal{S}$ be the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing $\left\{(r,s]:r,s\in \mathbb{Q}\right\}$. Show that $\mathcal{S}$ is the collection of Borel sets.

It is already assumed that $\mathcal{S}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra. Do I just need to show that every open set in $\mathbb{R}$ is in $\mathcal{S}$? Do I need to show that half-open intervals are Borel sets? Or are there other things to consider as well? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What definition of "Borel sets" are you using? There are many, many ways to define them.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. I mean the collection of Borel sets being the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing all open sets of $\mathbb{R}$, and elements of this collection are called Borel sets.

Comment: Then it's enough to show that all open sets are in $\mathcal S$.